# ¿Cómo obtener los valores en las posiciones 5 y 6 de una cadena?

Tags: java, android, string

Anteriormente recuperaba los últimos cuatro caracteres de una cadena haciendo esto:

```
String fechaHoy="20180213";
String santoMMDD = fechaHoy.substring(fechaHoy.length() - 4);
```

El resultado era: `0213`;

Ahora necesito obtener por separado:

- **a.** los últimos dos valores (`13`) en una variable
- **b.** los valores en las posiciones 5 y 6 (`02`) en otra variable

Los últimos dos no hay problema, lo podría hacer cambiando mi código original así:

```
String santoDD = fechaHoy.substring(fechaHoy.length() - 2);
```

Lo que no sé es cómo podría obtener los valores del caso **b.** ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

La cadena es siempre fija, es una representación de la fecha actual en formato `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: String sSubCadena = fechaHoy.substring(4,5); ???? 4,5 es de donde a donde quieres extraer

Comment: Como te ha dicho @LuisFernando, con el método substring() lo tienes (pasas como parámetro un origen y un fin). Además puedes extraer uno a uno los valores con el método charAt() indicando por parámetro la posición a extraer (este método devuelve un char)

Comment: El Javadoc del método `String.substring()` explica muy bien como utilizar este método. Te recomiendo que le eches un ojo para que lo entiendas. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo crearía un método para obtener los valores deseados en base a su posición, se puede modificar para que envié un error y no retorne resultado cuando el rango definido no es posible encontrar dentro de la cadena:

```
public static String getCadena(String s, int start, int end){
    String resultado="";
    try{
        resultado = s.substring(start-1, end);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("No existe rango definido!");
        //throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("No existe rango definido!");
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

de esta forma teniendo la cadena, se pueden obtener los valores deseados:

```
String fechaHoy="20180213";

String ano = getCadena(fechaHoy, 1,4);
String mes = getCadena(fechaHoy, 5,6);
String dia = getCadena(fechaHoy, 7,8);
```

Obteniendo los siguientes valores:

```
ano : 2018
mes : 02
dia : 13
```

Answer (score 1):

El mismo método *subString* te permite definir el indice inicial y el indice final menos una posición.

```
fechaHoy.substring(4, 6)
```

**Se usa 4** porque el indice empieza desde 0, entonces 4 sería la posición 5.

**Se usa 6** porque el método *subString* recibe como segundo argumento el indice final pero no lo toma, toma hasta una posición antes.

*Resultado:*

> 02

Answer (score 1):

Te bastaría con indicar los índices de principio y de fin para el caso b:

```
String fechaHoy="20180213";
//Caso A
String dia = fechaHoy.substring(fechaHoy.length() - 2);
// Caso B
String mes = fechaHoy.substring(4, 6);
```