# ¿Como generar una Contraseñar a través de 3 txtArea?

Tags: java, vistas

A traves de JavaFXML he unido 2 vistas, la primera tiene los botones para generar y el txtarea para recibir el resultado, la segunda vista tiene los txtareas a extraer.
Los txtarea son:

-Nombre
-Apellidos
-DNI

Extraer del nombre el primer carácter.
Extraer del apellido los 3 primeros.
Extraer del DNI los 4 últimos, siendo la letra siempre mayúscula.

No se como hacer las restricciones a la hora de generar la contraseña elija los caracteres que me piden.

Hago código en la vista secundaria:

```
  @FXML
private TextField txtnombre;
@FXML
private TextField txtapellido;
@FXML
private TextField txtdni;

//lo generamos para crear poder controlarlo desde la vista pricipal
public void Extraer(){
    String nombre = txtnombre.getText();
    String apellido =   txtapellido.getText();
    String dni =   txtdni.getText();
           
    
}
```

Código vista principal

```
    private TextField txtContr;
@FXML
private Vista2FXMLController panelController;

private void generarContraseña (ActionEvent e){
    //previamente limpiamos
    txtContr.clear();
    panelController.Extraer();
    

}
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿haciendo substring de las cadenas? Lo siento pero tu pregunta no se entiende bien. ¿Que es lo que no sabes? ¿Extraer partes de una cadena? con la función substring

Answer (score 1):

Para conseguir el primer caracter del nombre:

```
     String nombre = "Franco";
     String resultado1 = nombre.substring(0, 1); 
     System.out.println(resultado1);
```

**¿Por qué 0 (cero)?** Porque el índice empieza desde 0 (cero).

**¿Por qué 1 (uno)?** Porque el método `subString` recibe como segundo argumento el índice final pero no lo toma, toma hasta una posición antes.

Para conseguir los tres primeros caracteres del apellido:

```
     String apellido = "Balsamo";
     String resultado2 = apellido.substring(0, 3);
     System.out.println(resultado2);
```

Para conseguir los cuatro últimos caracteres del DNI:

```
     String DNI = "123456789";
     String resultado3 = DNI.substring(DNI.length() - 4);
     System.out.println(resultado3);
```

Ahora, para poner las letras en mayúsculas se usa el método `toUpperCase()`:

```
     String contrasena = resultado1 + resultado2 + resultado3;
     System.out.println(contrasena.toUpperCase());
```

Resultado esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Referencia**: [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/138154/131982)

Espero te sirva, ajústalo a tu forma.

Answer (score 1):

Quedó así, sin embargo lo quiero programar con un  botón y no me quedó funcionando.

```
   public String Extraer(){
String nombre = txtnombre.getText();
String apellido =   txtapellido.getText();
String dni =   txtdni.getText();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(nombre.substring(0,1));
    builder.append(apellido.substring(0,3));
    builder.append(dni.substring(dni.length() -4, dni.length()));   
    String result = builder.toString();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: ¿Lo solucionaste?

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias.
Lo tenía abandonado